# Please somebody explain this Javascript code step by step

Tags: javascript, loops

I learn Javascript I have found this code, but can't understand what it's doing. Please somebody explain it to me step by step

```
var ar1 = [1, 5, 6, 4, 3, 5, 100, -20];

function funDo(ar) {
    for (k = 0, i = 1, temp = ar.length - 1; k < temp; k++) i = (i <<
        1) + 1;
    for (; i > 0; i--) {
        for (k = 0, sum = 0, temp2 = []; k < ar.length; k++)
            if ((i >> (k)) % 2) {
                sum += ar[k];
                temp2.push(ar[k]);
            }
        if (sum == 10) console.log(temp2);
    }
}
funDo(ar1);
```

Comment: Why do you want to understand this code ? Try to understand JavaScript... try to understand simple, elegant and useful code. I will advise you against trying to understand this seemingly useless, "fun" code which simply does nothing interesting. Understanding this code will not help you with anything. It is just running two loops; doing some random ( afaik ) manipulation inside those loops and then printing some random ( afaik again ) number to the console. Better try to understand codes to known problems.

Comment: sometimes I have problems with loops, and this code is something like a task that I've received, but I see at this code and it's makes something unusefull as for me, that's why I'm asking for help, maybe I don't understand something. But thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`funDo(ar)` finds in (an integer array) `ar` "all sequences" of `ar`, which sum is `== 10` (..and logs them to console).

Feel free to comment, to ask for more details. :-)